# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare PHPMailerAutoload() out of the blue

Tags: php

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare PHPMailerAutoload() (previously declared in /home2/epsilonbr/ticket/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php:24) in /home2/epsilonbr/ticket/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php on line 24
```

Hello guys this was working till yesterday, suddenly today someone tried to send me a ticket and I received this error.
I am using the default mailer autoload I haven't changed anything

```
function PHPMailerAutoload($classname)
{
    //Can't use __DIR__ as it's only in PHP 5.3+
    $filename = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'class.'.strtolower($classname).'.php';
    if (is_readable($filename)) {
        require $filename;
    }
}

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.1.2', '>=')) {
    //SPL autoloading was introduced in PHP 5.1.2
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '>=')) {
        spl_autoload_register('PHPMailerAutoload', true, true);
    } else {
        spl_autoload_register('PHPMailerAutoload');
    }
} else {
    /**
     * Fall back to traditional autoload for old PHP versions
     * @param string $classname The name of the class to load
     */
    function __autoload($classname)
    {
        PHPMailerAutoload($classname);
    }
}
```

Any ideas on why this is happening? Line 24 is the `function PHPMailerAutoload($classname)`

Comment: The error message mentions the same file & line number in both places, so the most logical conclusion here is that you are _embedding_ this file in more than one location.

Comment: it's as you said mate, I thought I answered yday and deleted the question but apparently I was mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was really easy and as @CBroe said.

I had added the `require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';` twice in the code, once inside the header.php and the second time was inside the something_in_the_body.php file because I forgot that I had added that inside the header.

Answer (score -3):

```
public function E_mail($name,$from,$to,$title,$message)
{
 $this->email->from($from,$name);
 $this->email->to($to);
 $this->email->subject($title);
 $this->email->message($message);
 if($this->email->send()) 
  echo "Success";
     else 
        echo "Fail";
}
```

Comment: Actually what @cbroe said was correct, I had added `require_once` the file twice, once in the header and once in the body (cause I forgot the first)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does the given code change the behaviour of the autoloader?

Comment: Nothing in this answer is related to the problem the OP was having.